# php domdocument: when i create an xml, how can i ident each element properly?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

When i create an XML using php's DomDocument it creates the xml properly but all the elements
are in one line, the xml file itself is not so readable.

I searched in google and find that the attribute formatOutput in DomDocument should resolve the issue, i use php 5.3 and i do not have this properly in DomDocument.

any ideas?

Comment: What are you using to save it? The examples for `saveXML` seem to be formatted correctly: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php

Comment: @Jamie Wong its down to the `$doc->formatOutput = true;` line

Comment: @seengee - ah. Should have read that more carefully

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this..

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
```

I see you said that you're using 5.3 and this isn't working but nothing in the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) implies that this has been deprecated though

Comment: oh.. code completion didn't provide this parameter so i thought it wasn't available. thanks

Comment: you might have to set `preserveWhiteSpace` to `false` though as well